# Getting an exception when putting string before while

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code to get data from a file

```
 try {
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new  InputStreamReader(openFileInput(TEXTFILE));
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String string;
        StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((string=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            stringbuilder.append(string);
        }
        EditText.setText(stringbuilder.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It works but
when I put the `string=bufferedReader.readLine()` before `While`, I get an exception : `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: Can you post the updated code that throws an OutOfMemoryException?  My guess is you aren't updating the `string` variable so it loops forever and keeps appending the same string over and over to your builder until you run out of memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading a line from the `BufferedReader`, and storing the result in `string`. After that, you check if `string != null`, and if not, you append `string` to `stringbuilder`. You're repeating this until `string == null`.

The confusion here might be the comparison of an assignment statement:

```
while ((string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { ... }
```

This is a short notation of the following:

```
string = bufferedReader.readLine();
while (string != null) {
    ...
    string = bufferedReader.readLine();
}
```

Comment: @dkatzel what do you mean? My last snippet does execute `readLine()` every iteration.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I didn't see the last assignment. you're correct

Comment: So, why when I put 'string=bufferedReader.readLine()' before 'while' , I get   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: @A.V How big is the file? Is it really a text file, or is it perhaps some large binary file?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom It's just a tiny text file

Comment: @A.V Then I haven't a clue